# is it possible to put more than one html5 files in android app developed with dreamweaver cs5.5?

Tags: android, html

can we freely put more than one html5 file in android app developed with dreamweaver cs5.5?
example:

```
page1.html  
page2.html  
page3.html
```

then provide hyperlinks between the pages?

I tried doing this but the browser refuses to load the pages.

Comment: We need to know how you tried. Because otherwise the only answer we can offer you is: "Yes. It is possible to put more than one HTML5 files in an Android app"

Comment: Thanks for your affirmation. I tried doing this again, after knowing that it can be done..after a bit of working out, what i came up with is that i have to use this syntax for navigating between these files : <a rel="external" href="page2.html">. is this right? i think i have to do more homework before i ask such silly questions..thanks for your concern..

Answer (score 0):

If you have your HTML files in the assets folder, say in a subfolder in `/assets/html/`, the following would work...

Java code could look something like this:

```
private void displayHTML5Page(String filename) {
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/index.html");
        setContentView(webView);
```

In HTML you access other pages using something like:

```
<a href="file:///android_asset/html/anotherpage.html">Here's a Second Page</a>
<a href="file:///android_asset/html/anotherpage2.html">Here's a Third Page</a>
<a href="file:///android_asset/html/anotherpage3.html">Here's a Fourth Page</a>
....
```